# Reg: how to setup web based portal authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

we need to setup multi factor authentication for web based application portal  in AWS.
how can we set it.

Comment: can you please explain more , you need the MFA for aws console or another app?

Comment: thanks Moussab Kbeisy, we have web portal hosted in s3, in that web portal we need to setup MFA.

Comment: You will need a backend API to handle MFA. 
How do you handle authentication now?

Comment: am using user level MFA, though IAM MFA virtual manage, also on EC2 MFA through google authenticator, is there any way to  set MFA same like for web portal also in AWS.

Comment: can you suggest some steps how can i setup MFA for my webportal which is hosted in AWS and using.

Comment: can we setup through AWS cognito, any steps how to setup MFA from AWS cognito on web portal hosted in AWS.

Comment: authentication through username and password only on web portal as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements.
Setting up MFA for cognito users and using a custom web portal. I suggest you take a look here:

It goes from setting up cognito to setting up de webportal with MFA.

https://link.medium.com/bAGyjLr5ijb

Comment: Thanks Dharman, how to upgrade EKS cluster in kubernetics